# Difference between Java bytecode and Kotlin bytecode

Tags: java, android, kotlin, compilation, bytecode

When we compile Kotlin source code, is it converted to **Kotlin bytecode** or **Java bytecode** only?

Comment: don't confuse `java` and `jvm`. java is just one language that can run on the `JVM`, and there are many `VM` implementations. `kotlin`, `scala`, `groovy` all compile code into bytecode that `JVM` can run

Comment: might be silly, but what if decompile Kotlin compiled bytecode will it return into Kotlin again?

Comment: if the decompiler would do that, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin bytecodes and Java bytecodes use the same bytecode instruction set; namely JVM bytecodes as specified by the JVM specification.

However, there may be differences in the way that JVM bytecodes are used for the two languages.  These may cause affect the output of a decompiler.

The other complicating factor is that on Android the JVM bytecodes will be converted to Android Davlik bytecodes or ART (native) code before execution.